# Environment variable not found in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy

My jenkinsfile starts out with something like this:

```
pipeline {
    environment {
      stackName = "jenkins5"
    }

    agent any
    options {
        lock(resource: "${stackName}", inversePrecedence: false)
    }
```

When I run the corresponding job, I get

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: stackName for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

How come?

I tried using env.stackName but it just gets evaluated to "null" instead of "jenkins5".

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it happening in cause of jenkins reads options before the environment step.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably list in variable as below:

```
pipeline {
agent any 
environment {
      stackName = "jenkins5"
    }
options {
        lock(label: 'resource1', variable: 'stackName', , inversePrecedence: false)
    }
```

for more information : https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/lockable-resources/